# how to record only audio/only video of RTMP stream with Red5

Tags: red5

I have a client that publishes RTMP to Red5 server (both audio and video).
I want to record only audio OR only video from the published stream.
Is there any API in Red5 which allows such filtering of recording?

My Red5 vesion is 1.0
And, in 'org.red5.server.api.stream.IBroadcastStream' class, I couldn't find a method which can mute OR drop the video/audio from RTMP stream

Please Help.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own RecordingListener and add / remove them from your streams. These listeners would be coded in such a way that they ignore the audio or video when writing the files. The listeners would be added on your command, via your client or some other means by gaining access to the ClientBroadcastStream. Here is the area that you check the data type coming in: https://github.com/Red5/red5-server-common/blob/master/src/main/java/org/red5/server/stream/RecordingListener.java#L247